# Construct crispy forms layouts iteratively?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm currently trying to render a form that will allow our users to edit products, currently the form is being displayed all as one long column.

It has been requested that I split it into two columns but am having issues due to the `ModelForm` being generated using `modelform_factory()`

Is there any way in which I can generate a Crispy layout object that can insert new div's every two form objects?

Note: the length of the form is not known beforehand.

View Code:

```
def layout_from_form(form, columns=2):
    field_count = sum(1 for i in form)  # form specified it's iterable but is not len() friendly
    for field_number, _ in enumerate(form):

        if field_number % columns == 0:

            max_length_field = field_number + 2
            if field_number + 2 > field_count:
                max_length_field = field_count
            try:
                selected_forms = form.helper[field_number:max_length_field]
                selected_forms.wrap(Div, css_class="span6")
                selected_forms.wrap_together(Div, css_class="row-fluid")
            except:
                assert False, (field_count, field_number, max_length_field)


def edit_product(request, bought_in_control_panel_id, item_uuid):

    boughtin_model = get_model_for_bought_in_control_panel(bought_in_control_panel_id)
    item = boughtin_model.objects.get(pk=item_uuid)
    BoughtinForm = modelform_factory(boughtin_model, exclude=("uuid", "date_time_updated", "date_time_created",
                                                              "manufacturer"))
    if request.method == "POST":
        boughtin_form = BoughtinForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if boughtin_form.is_valid():
            boughtin_form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('view_product', kwargs={'bought_in_control_panel_id': bought_in_control_panel_id,
                                                            'item_uuid': item_uuid}))
    else:
        boughtin_form = BoughtinForm(instance=item)

        boughtin_form.helper = FormHelper(boughtin_form)
        boughtin_form.helper.form_action = reverse('edit_product', kwargs={'bought_in_control_panel_id': bought_in_control_panel_id,
                                                                           'item_uuid': item_uuid})
        boughtin_form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
        layout_from_form(boughtin_form)
    return render_to_response('suppliers/products/edit_product.html', {'item': item,
                                                                       'boughtin_form': boughtin_form,
                                                                       'bought_in_control_panel_id': bought_in_control_panel_id})
```

Example Layout Object:

```
Layout(
    Div(
        Field('name'),
        Field('type'),
        css_class="row-fluid"
    ),
    Div(
        Field('uuid'),
        Field('dave'),
        css_class="row-fluid"
    ),
    .... Etc ad infinitum ....
)
```

Comment: In what way is the length of the form not known beforehand?

Comment: Have you seen "updating layouts on the go" from the crispy-form docs?: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html  In particular, the [wrap](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#wrap) action might be exactly what you are looking for.

It feels like you could determine the length of an incoming form (of variable length) in a view and create a dynamic layout that way.

Comment: well, I don't know how to get a count of fields on a form that's been generated by modelform_factory, and I can't rely on the same model being passed each time.

Comment: also, i don't have a layout object to begin with which that page seems to require, i'm trying to set one up dynamically.

Comment: There is a way to determine the length of an object that has been generated with a modelform_factory.  Take a look at this pastebin I just created: http://bpaste.net/show/UEtjVLkKCEV3MYQA8E0E/

Comment: Maybe you start with an empty form class, that constructs a FormHelper() class in `__init__`, and then add fields on the fly, per the Crispy docs. 

Your logic could determine when to drop in a Div, Field, etc class as you iterate over the fields in form.base_fields.keys().

To me, this feels like an excellent use case for crispy-forms.  Thoughts?

Comment: thank you very much :) make this into an answer, and i'll accept it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In your question: "Note: the length of the form is not known beforehand."

We can indeed find the length of a form beforehand:

```
>>> import apps.students.models as models
>>> from django.forms.models import modelform_factory
>>> form = modelform_factory(models.StudentProfileBasics)
>>> len(form.base_fields.keys())
5
```

From there, the combination of a) Crispy's ability to [modify layouts on the go](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#updating-layouts-on-the-go) by grabbing slices of a layout, b) the [wrap](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamic_layouts.html#wrap) method that Crispy provides, and c) the list provided by forms.Form.base_fields.keys() should get you where you need to be!